# Different gcc output for __builtin_clzll on different optimisation levels and wrapped in a function

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am puzzled on the behavior / output of the following code, either this is a bug or I am missing something. (Ubuntu 16.04 on skylake arch)

```
#include <iostream>

int wrap(unsigned long long val) {
    return __builtin_clzll(val);
} 

using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << __builtin_clzll(0) << " " << wrap(0) << endl;
    cout << __builtin_clzll(1) << " " << wrap(1) << endl;
    cout << __builtin_clzll(2) << " " << wrap(2) << endl;
}
```

and here are different outputs on different compile settings. I do know that clz may return an undefined result if zero is passed. However the directly inlined call works always fine, but as soon as stack is involved the compiler messes up.

```
snk@maggy:~/HCS$ g++ -O0 test.cpp -o test
snk@maggy:~/HCS$ ./test
64 4196502
63 63
62 62
snk@maggy:~/HCS$
```

The -O > 0 levels do not change result, I guess gcc is inlining. This is the expected result...

```
snk@maggy:~/HCS$ g++ -O1 test.cpp -o test
snk@maggy:~/HCS$ ./test
64 64
63 63
62 62
```

It gets even better with -mlzcnt:

```
snk@maggy:~/HCS$ g++ -O0 -mlzcnt test.cpp -o test
snk@maggy:~/HCS$ ./test
64 0
63 0
62 1

snk@maggy:~/HCS$ g++ -O1 -mlzcnt test.cpp -o test
snk@maggy:~/HCS$ ./test
64 64
63 63
62 62

snk@maggy:~/HCS$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Thanks,
Ch

Comment: You should not expect that undefined behaviour will result in any particular result (not even the same result twice). That's why it's undefined.

Comment: Results or behaviors going undefined generally means the whole program is no longer reliable.

Comment: I suspect that when optimizing, `__builtin_clzll(<constant>)` is being evaluated at compile time - and attempts to provide a reasonable answer, despite the documentation describing the result as *undefined*. Without a disasm, the value `4196502` is puzzling though.

Comment: `__builtin_clzll` is GCC goodness and only handles non-0 values. Intel's [`LZCNT`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LZCNT.html), which is part of BMI, can handle a 0 value.

Comment: You missed one essential point. You did not read the documentation. **for zero result is UB.**

Comment: @PeterJ - he *states* that he is aware of this in the second paragraph. It's a bit rich to accuse someone of not reading the documentation, when you haven't read the question. To some of us, the results are interesting in and of themselves.

Comment: Yeah. Wrapped and unwrapped UB. I have missed the second paragraph, when I saw the UB. Voting to close as it is pointless to discuss better or less optimized wrapped and unwrapped UBs,

Comment: Ps I have compiled it and had only UB on value 0. Another ones were executing ok. Maybe bug in your version

Answer (score 6):

The interesting case in this question is the behaviour with `-mlzcnt`. This was reported as [GCC bug 58928](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58928) in 2013 but the bug report was later retracted, because it is "expected" behaviour when you supply `-mlzcnt` for Intel CPUs which do not support the `LZCNT` opcode.

As it turns out, `LZCNT` is a `BSR` (Bit Search Reverse) with a `F3` prefix; on Intel CPUs which don't implement LZCNT, rather than being trapped as an invalid opcode, it is interpreted as a BSR, which returns the bit position of the 1-bit (with bit 0 being the low-order bit), rather than the number of preceding 0s.

As indicated, invoking `__builtin_clz` with argument 0 produces undefined behaviour. You should have no expectations about the result of undefined behaviour; not even that it will be the same result twice.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [GCC documentation for built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (bold text added)

> Built-in Function: *int* **__builtin_clz** (*unsigned int x*)
>
> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in *x*, starting at the most
> significant bit position. **If *x* is 0, the result is undefined**.
>
> ...
>
> Built-in Function: *int* **__builtin_clzll** (*unsigned long long*)
>
> Similar to `__builtin_clz`, except the argument type is `unsigned long long`.

The result for `0` is undefined.

Comment: The OP *knows* this, and already stated it as a potential source of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at `wrap` without optimizations:

```
        .globl wrap(unsigned long long)
wrap(unsigned long long):

        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp

        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        bsrq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        xorq    $63, %rax

        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Both AMD and Intel *do not modify* the destination register if the source is `(0)` - though I believe only AMD documents this behaviour. In effect, you are getting whatever `%rax` was previously set to (it is not a caller saved register - it used for certain return values), xor'd with `(63)`. So `%rax` could be set to some 'previous' result. Possibly even subject to the results of [address space randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

The stack for this function is not the culprit. The first argument in the x86-64 ELF (and OS X Mach-O) ABI is passed in `%rdi`. The lack of optimization spills it to memory on the stack frame, but it is still storing `(0)` at `-8(%rbp)` here.

TL;DR - `%rax` holds irrelevant junk on entry, and is not modified by a `(0)` source operand to `bsr`. The `xor` might flip a few low bits.